# "Parametrized" database model & backend storage system as well as data mining manipulation

Tags: database, algorithm, architecture, data-structures

I have implicitly made this a community wiki seeing that the answers can be quite broad.
I'm working with a start-up company to accomplish the following goal.

In a medical research, a patient medical record can have infinite amount of data regarding a patient for a specific diagnosis, e.g. a smoker has a higher chance of catching lung cancer but that doesn't necessarily mean that a non-smoker can catch lung cancer. My goal is to create/use a database model that can deal with such parameters.

Now, I also have to come up with ways to data mine these parametrized data to create statistical data e.g. see the trends on all 40 year old female who suffered from lung cancer. That report can be generic, (graph, tabular, etc.) where doctors can see trends or analyse possible solutions that can work....

My questions are:
1) Which Database systems allows for parametrized backend storage (e.g. Cassandra) that can easily be used in java, and is very efficient in data retrieval, linkage, etc. We are dealing with high amount of patient records per states.

2) What algorithms or AI techniques can I use for data mining? Is there any mining techniques out there that can help me do this?

**PS** How does Google Analytics deal with parametrised data?

***PPS*** A parametrized data is data which has a key, and data where data can be value, another key-value pair, a list of value, a set of parametrized data (organized, unorganized)

I'm looking forward for suggestive answers! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, this is how we have implemented this.

We created a **keyspace** called `medical` and a supercolumn family called `patient`.

under the supercolumn family, we have a `general` supercolumn which basically store the patient details, and another supercolumn called `operation` to keep recording of the user occupation.

Don't forget that the `general` supercolumn keeps record of the patient as he/she comes to the doctor. That way, we know exactly the patient's exact condition before, during and after operation.

I know some data can be duplicates, but no supercolumns can be identical as there is no way that you can have exactly 2 different patient of identical attributes and sickness.

So basically, Cassandra allows 3 layers of abstraction, Keyspace, Column/Supercolumn family, Column/Supercolumn.

Hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your first question only.

Cassandra is a key-value datastore (in your case *parametrized*). If you use Cassandra, you need higher computation time to derive complex reports. The reason being - it stores data in raw format. Cassandra like NOSQL databases are good if you want to scale very very big. They are [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) and compromise on data replication and latency.

In your case as a patient can have data in infinitely any form, try to fit the model of a Triple Store (Semantic Web frameworks like Jena, OpenSesame, etc). They allow you to have a lousy data structures and can be molded at runtime. Also, their querying engines (SPARQL, SeRQL) give you more power than NOSQL stores (like Cassandra), but these querying capabilities are obviously lesser than RDBMS.